# Make a group of divs fit automatically on the screen without overflowing down or right with flexbox. (no scrolling)

Tags: css, height, width, flexbox

So I need to create a layout as in the two screenshots down below.
In portrait mode: 4 rows with each 4 divs and 2 on the last row.
In landscape mode: 2 rows with 7 divs each.

It was easy to make 4 and 2 rows with the following css:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
.cat_div{
  width:14.2vw; // for 7 items per row → 2 rows
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
.cat_div{
  width:25vw; // for 4 items per row → 4 rows
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** The tricky part that I can't seem to get right!

*No scrolling down allowed!* It needs to fit on any window size. So the divs need to become larger and smaller depending on the size, so the user never has to scroll down.

I've played around for a few hours now, but I cannot seem to get the desired result. Could anyone have a look at my code?

**My full code with snippet:**

```css
.cat_icon {
  background-color:goldenrod;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius:50%;

}
.cat_div{
  border:lightgrey solid thin;
  margin:0.5vw;
}
#cat_btn_container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
#cat_btn_container{
  height:80vh;
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
.cat_div{
  width:22.5vw;
height:50%;
}
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .cat_div{
width:12.5vw;
height:50%;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cat_btn_container">
  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
    <label>Category 1</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_div">
    <div class="cat_icon"></div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </body>
```

**The same snippet on JS BIN:**
http://jsbin.com/layaxi/edit?html,css,output

**The desired result:**

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted here. The question is really thorough... If anyone can please advice me how I should edit the question to be more up to the SO standards let me know. I hope to reach at least a rating of 0 again on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap grids with columns (they need to add to 12 in each row) is the best way for full responsiveness. You can use media queries too, but there are classes in bootstrap for many screen sizes.

Comment: I want to avoid Bootstrap because it's not a bootstrap powered website, and bootstrap often causes more conflict in my experience. Also I cannot fit 7 divs in 12 columns ... And the main problem is the overflow to the bottom... I updated my question for more clarification.